# Selenium Python - Check if a field is required or not

Tags: python, selenium

I need to check which fields are required and extract the name of the field (the innerText).

In this example I would need to get "Supervisory Organization" and "Worker Type". However the "WOEG WBEG WAFG" is used for non required fields too so I need to rely on the "WMEG WHGG" class type.
[image]

```
<li class="WMEG WHGG" role="presentation" data-automation-id="formLabelRequired">
   <div class="WOEG WBEG WAFG">
      <label id="56$565285--uid6-formLabel" data-automation-id="formLabel" for="56$565285--uid6-input">Supervisory Organization</label>
<li class="WMEG WHGG" role="presentation" data-automation-id="formLabelRequired">
   <div class="WOEG WBEG WAFG">
      <label id="56$565284-input--uid11-input-formLabel" data-automation-id="formLabel" for="56$565284-input--uid11-input">Worker Type</label>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: Does that have place holder ?

Comment: @cruisepandey there are no place holders

Comment: i know how it can possibly be checked but without more details I risk of wasting my time on answering this question. Both label are located inside `formLabelRequired` which probably means that both are required. `OEG WBEG WAFG` is just a child class of a required field.This question is confusing. More details are needed, at least a screenshot of this form.

Comment: HI @vitaliis I have added a screenshot of the form.

Comment: Update html with 'Copy Details...' field data. Then it will be possible to check the difference.

Comment: Also, html of the form (parent of these li classes) itself would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps

```
listItems = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
for e in listItems:
    isRequired = e.get_attribute("data-automation-id")
    if isRequired!="" and "Required" in isRequired:
        print(e.find_element_by_xpath(".//div/label").text)
```

Comment: THank you, it worked perfectly! Sorry for missing details, it is my first post on stackoverflow. :)

Comment: Not a problem :)